# Class not found in Laravel 4 even after updating in composer and start/global.php

Tags: oop, laravel

I'm having trouble using a custom class in Laravel 4.

In a new directory `app/library` there is `NewClass.php`

Here is the class:

```php
<?

class NewClass {    
  public static function jjj()
  {
    return 'hello';
  }
}
```

The library folder has been registered in `composer.json`:

```json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/library"
    ]
```

and also in `app/start/global.php`:

```php
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

app_path().'/commands',
app_path().'/controllers',
app_path().'/models',
app_path().'/database/seeds',
app_path().'/library',

));
```

Following this, I have done `php artisan dump-autoload`, `clear-compiled`, `optimize` as well as `composer update` in CLI. All operations were performed without error.

Now when I try to access the class - either by instantiating and calling the jjj() method or calling it statically from anywhere from the app, I get class not found exception.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'NewClass' not found
```

Now, what have I overlooked - why is this not working??

Comment: Minor detail, does your php.ini configured with enable short tag cause  I see that you're using ```<?``` instead of ```<?php```. I would advice using the latter.

Comment: did you run `composer update` ?

Comment: that was it, crynobone - never would have spotted it myself. changed that to <?php and viola. thanks a lot for pointing that out crynobone. noob mistake - thank you!